# Rails 3 superclass mismatch for class Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, superclass

I'm running Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.1.0.

This error has popped up in a seemingly random fashion. I only have one Location class in my app. But I did add several new gems recently: Rmagick, CarrierWave and CarrierWave-Azure.

Here's the error:

```
TypeError in CompaniesController#show

superclass mismatch for class Location
app/models/location.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:24:in `show'
```

If I go to companies_controller.rb ln 24 there is this code:

```
@addresses = @company.addresses
```

Line 23: actually references Location:

```
@locations = @company.locations
```

If I step through the code in debug mode the @locations variable isn't created anymore when line 23 executes, all other variables prior to line 23 are created. I haven't touched this code in months, the only recent additions to the codebase have revolved around the gems I listed above but did not include changes to Location.rb, Company.rb, Address.rb or Companies_Controller.

Anyone know what's going on here? thx!

Update:
Here is my Location model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :address_attributes, :address, :created_by, :is_active, :location_name, :location_type_id, 
  :region_id, :updated_by, :website

 # set schema name and table name for TakebackDBMS  
 self.table_name ="recycle.Location"



 # define associations
 has_many :companyContacts
 belongs_to :location_type
 belongs_to :company
 belongs_to :address
 belongs_to :region
 default_scope order: 'location_name' # return locations list in Alphabetical order 


 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => :all_blank

 #validations
 validates :location_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
 validates :created_by, length: { maximum: 50 }

end
```

Comment: Post your `Location` model.

Comment: Location model posted

Comment: Looks like one of your **`gems/plugins`** already defines a `Location Class`.So is the error.

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: Thanks Pavan! I thought that may be the problem but was hoping there was a different solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of your **`gems/plugins`** already defines a **`Location Class`**.So is the error.

To resolve this,you should be changing your **`Location`** class in your app to some name like **`Location1`**

```
class Location1 < ActiveRecord::Base
```

This should solve your problem.And don't forget to change your **`Model`** file name to **`location1.rb`**